# In drupal7 webform how to get the ip address

Tags: drupal

I need to get the client IP instead I am getting server IP.

My code

```
$submission     =   (object)array(
'nid'           =>  $webform_nid,
'uid'           =>  0,
'submitted'     =>  REQUEST_TIME,
'remote_addr'   =>  ip_address(),
'is_draft'      =>  FALSE,
'serial'        =>  $serial,
'data'          =>  $data,
);
```

Can anyone please tell me why I am getting the server IP?

Answer (score 0):

Not really in the Drupal way but you can use superglobal
`$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]`

> "The IP address from which the user is viewing the current page."

http://php.net/manual/fr/reserved.variables.server.php